# Can't parse bs4 src attribute using the getattr() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, getattr

I've created a script to parse two fields from every movie container from a webpage. The script is doing fine.

I'm trying to use this `getattr()` function to scrape text and src from two fields, as in `movie_name` and `image_link`. In case of `movie_name`, it works. However, it fails when I try to parse `image_link`.

There is a function currently commented out which works when I uncomment. However, my goal here is to make use of `getattr()` to parse `src`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://yts.am/browse-movies"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

# def get_information(url):
#     res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
#     soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
#     for row in soup.select(".browse-movie-wrap"):
#         movie_name = row.select_one("a.browse-movie-title").text
#         image_link = row.select_one("img.img-responsive").get("src")
#         yield movie_name,image_link

def get_information(url):
    res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for row in soup.select(".browse-movie-wrap"):
        movie_name = getattr(row.select_one("a.browse-movie-title"),"text",None)
        image_link = getattr(row.select_one("img.img-responsive"),"src",None)
        yield movie_name,image_link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for items in get_information(url):
        print(items)
```

> How can I scrape `src` using `getattr()` function?

Comment: "src" is not an attribute of the `select_one` output in the Python sense of the word.  You're expected to use the `get` method to fetch the tag's attributes (in the HTML sense of the word).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works:

```
movie_name = getattr(row.select_one("a.browse-movie-title"),"text",None)
```

But this doesn't:

```
image_link = getattr(row.select_one("img.img-responsive"),"src",None)
```

is because *methods of a class are also attributes*. So, effectively, what you're doing is getting a *function* **text** for the first example. In other words, there's no method or attribute called `src`.

If you look at `attributes` of:

```
row.select_one("a.browse-movie-title").attrs
```

You'll get:

```
{'href': 'https://yts.mx/movies/imperial-blue-2019', 'class': ['browse-movie-title']}
```

Likewise, for

```
row.select_one(".img-responsive").attrs
```

The output is:

```
{'class': ['img-responsive'], 'src': 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/imperial_blue_2019/medium-cover.jpg', 'alt': 'Imperial Blue (2019) download', 'width': '170', 'height': '255'}
```

So, if we experiment and do this:

```
getattr(row.select_one(".img-responsive"), "attrs", None).src
```

We'll end up with:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'src'
```

Therefore, as mentioned in the comments, this is not how you'd use `getattr()` in pure Python sense on `bs4` objects. You can either use the `.get()` method or the `[key]` syntax.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}


def get_information(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')
    for row in soup.select(".browse-movie-wrap"):
        movie_name = row.select_one("a.browse-movie-title").getText()
        image_link = row.select_one("img.img-responsive").get("src")
        yield movie_name, image_link


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for items in get_information("https://yts.am/browse-movies"):
        print(items)
```

This produces:

```
('Imperial Blue', 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/imperial_blue_2019/medium-cover.jpg')
('Ablaze', 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/ablaze_2001/medium-cover.jpg')
('[CN] Long feng zhi duo xing', 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/long_feng_zhi_duo_xing_1984/medium-cover.jpg')
('Bobbie Jo and the Outlaw', 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/bobbie_jo_and_the_outlaw_1976/medium-cover.jpg')
('Adam Resurrected', 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/adam_resurrected_2008/medium-cover.jpg')
('[ZH] The Wasted Times', 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/the_wasted_times_2016/medium-cover.jpg')
('Promise', 'https://img.yts.mx/assets/images/movies/promise_2021/medium-cover.jpg')

and so on ...
```

Finally, if you *really* want to parse this with `getattr()` you can try this:

```
movie_name = getattr(row.select_one("a.browse-movie-title"), "getText", None)()
image_link = getattr(row.select_one("img.img-responsive"), "attrs", None)["src"]
```

And you'll still get the same results, but, IMHO, this is way too complicated and not too readable either than a plain `.getText()` and `.get("src")` syntax.